# Write a program that prints sum, product and quotient of two input integers in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm new to the language and all this overflow problems and integer types are getting on my nerves. here is what I have but when I run it I get,

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int one, two, s, q, m;
   s = one+two
   q = one/two
   m = one*two
   printf("Enter first positive integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &one);
   printf("Enter second positive integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &two);
   printf("The addition of %d and %d is %d", one, two, s);
   printf("The integer division of %d divided by %d is %d", one, two, q);
   printf("the multiplication of %d and %d is %d", &one, &two, m);
   return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You do compile this code, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

You should perform the calculations after you've got the input.

```
printf("Enter first positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &one);
printf("Enter second positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &two);

s = one+two;
q = one/two;
m = one*two;
```

Comment: this fixed it, thanks! the semicolons weren't really the issue it's just the way I copied/pasted the code on here that made them not show up by mistake. I was having a problem with running the program, linux is confusing!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int one, two;
printf("Enter first positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &one);
printf("Enter second positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &two);
printf("The addition of %d and %d is %d", one, two, (one+two));
printf("The integer division of %d divided by %d is %d", one, two, (one/two));
printf("the multiplication of %d and %d is %d", &one, &two, (one*two));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: and another thing, you have to check if your `two` is `zero` as in `0`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semicolons after

```
   s = one+two
   q = one/two
   m = one*two
```

Plus you should perform the calculations after you read the input but that's a different problem.

Comment: if you have a semicolon, still have to get the values for `one` and `two`.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow: Yes but that's not the problem which prevents him from compiling in the first place.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow: then your answer is also not correct logically. If second number is zero then division will fail

Comment: @Mindhun, have you read the comment on my answer and the time I wrote the comment?

Answer (score 0):

These lines makes the problem:

```
s = one+two
q = one/two
m = one*two
```

You missed the `;` (semicolon)

Change it like:

```
s = one+two;
q = one/two;
m = one*two;
```

Also read the input from user first before doing the operations.

Comment: even you have semicolon, the program still have to ask for the values of `one` and `two`.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow: answered for the problem that OP have. Correcting the whole code is not my job. I just a give a clue for the problem

Comment: @Mindhun MP, I understand your point but the way you answer the problem can pawn to another problem.